# Getting the source of a delegated tap event

Tags: events, sencha-touch-2

Okay, so it took some digging here, I hope the solution I found is useful. I hope even more, though, that there is a less jacked-up way to do this, and someone can point it out.

I was trying to figure out how to get the source of a delegated tap event from an item that is  in a carousel, rather than a list or other similar structure with built-in passable arguments in Sencha Touch 2; the scope of the event is, by default, the container that has the listener. All of the arguments that were passed through the function were related to the mouse click event, rather than the source. See below for my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like I said, this is a hacky solution, if there's something better that'd be awesome, please post it here. Anyway, this is the delegate listener code I used:

```
{
    element:    'element',
    delegate:   '.completed_button',
    event:      'tap',
    fn: function(element){
        var source_id = element.getTarget().id;
        Ext.getCmp(source_id);
    }
}
```

In other words, pass the click event argument, get its target, and get that target's id. I found this through snooping around what `console.log(element)` showed me.

Answer (score 2):

One more way

```
tap: function(list, index, target, record, e, eOpts){
    var elm = Ext.get(e.target);
    Ext.getCmp(elm.dom.id);
}
```

Comment: Nice! What would be the context here? I'm guessing it would be on a Ext.getCmp('item').on({}) operation?

Comment: you can even get the elements class name and other html attributes that you want/change by elm.dom.className etc